# Transfer Learning completely different domain and task

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning

I've been reading some papers and blog posts on **Transfer Learning**. What I realized is that some say "different" and others say "different but similar". Now, I'm confused.

Say that,

`D` is domain. `T` is task.
`a` is source, hence source domain is `Da` and source task is `Ta`.
`a'` is different but similar to a.
`b` is different from a.
`Ms` is the source model learned from `Da` and `Ta`.
`Mt` is the target model.

In which target domain-task combination, Ms can transfer its knowledge to Mt?

```
1. (Da, Tb)
2. (Db, Ta)
3. (Da', Tb)
4. (Db, Ta')
5. (Da', Ta)
6. (Da, Ta')
7. (Da', Ta')
8. (Db, Tb)
```

Honestly, I know 5, 6, 7 are possible since the paper said so. And I doubt 8 will work (won't it?).

But what about 1, 2, 3, 4 where either domain or task is b?

Comment: This is a tough question and I think the answer is still open to research. From my experience a pretrained model is always better than starting from scratch, even when transfering to a totally different domain/task. Btw you should link the paper you mention in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What's a "domain"?

In the field of natural language processing (NLP) there's a lot of research for domain adaptation, and you can get some benefit in all the cases (#1-#8) you describe regarding for what NLP would call "different domains" - e.g. newswire text vs tweet text vs clinical radiology report text; yes, even in #8.

However, you can have *more different* "domains" (which wouldn't be really called domains IMHO) - for example, english text vs chinese text; or english text vs english audio recordings. It is possible do do some transfer learning even in those cases, but much more limited; so it really depends on where you draw the line between "that's a different domain" vs "that's a completely different type of input data".

Answer (score 2):

It depends how different the source and target domains are. If the source and target domains have no similarities then you can’t improve your model for a task in the target domain by pre-training on the task domain. However if there are similarities e.g. any image domain to almost any other image domain, and your source domain dataset is large, transferring your model from the source domain to the target domain is likely to help regularise your model and improve generalisation in the target domain. Especially if the target domain dataset is small.

In deep learning you want to reinitialise (retrain from random weights) more layers (from the top down) and do more fine tuning depending on how different your source and target domains and source and target tasks are.